# Semaphore of size 1 the best option?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, semaphore, java.util.concurrent

If you have a resource that only once person should access at a time you could use a semaphore of size one or you could just use a single ReentrantLock instance?

What are the subtle difference that make one or the other the better decision?

Comment: Why not `synchronized`?

Comment: I don't think there will be any - when `permits` is set to 1, the 2 APIs become almost identical. And both implementations are based on `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` so behaviour and performance should be close to identical too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are differences:

1. Semaphores can be acquired by one thread and released by another thread. This way, one thread can signal another thread. Semaphores with count 1 can also be used for mutual exclusion. Locks on the other hand are used only for mutual exclusion.
2. Semaphores are not reentrant. This means a thread cannot acquire a semaphore when the permits are exhausted even if it has been acquired by the same thread. Locks can be reentrant.

Answer (score 1):

`Semaphore`s are good for counting permits/releases, so if you have more than one resource, `Lock` etal. will not help you much. But if you have only one resource to guard, they are good enough.

Comment: @Raif H absolutely zero difference then?  Only thing I can think of is if you are not 100% sure it will always be a limit of 1.

Comment: Like assylias said, they (and many others in `java.util.concurrent`) are based on `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` and will have the same performance characteristics. Pick the one with the right semantics for you.

Answer (score 0):

Counting Semaphore Example: You have a protected object, with a restriction of not more than five threads are allowed to access it concurrently. In that case a counting semaphore of initial value 5 is the mathematical fit. [Downey's Little book of Semaphores](http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores/) is one of the best reads to understand the constructs.

Comment: While true, I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that this can be done with both `synchronized` and `Semaphore` you first must figure out how you will use this resource. If you use `synchronized` this means that you will have to watch on synchronization in threads:

```
public void run() {
  // some code
  synchronized (resource) {
    // use resource
  }
}
```

If you don't want to let threads watch for this (which is in my opinion better), use `Semaphore` in getter method of resource:

```
public Resource acquireResource() {
  // acquire semaphore
  return resource;
}

public void releaseResource() {
  // release semaphore
}
```

and in thread just do:

```
public void run() {
  // some code
  Resource resource = ResourceContainer.getResource();
  // do something with resource
  releaseResource();
}
```

You can add `Object` parameter to these methods just to compare if same object released semaphore.